# How to teach `crush` to unfold definitions?

Tags: automation, coq

How do I teach `crush` (from [Chlipala's cpdt](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/)) to unfold automatically `def` in the following example:

```
(*Simplified version of `crush` which for this example suffices *)
Ltac crush' := autorewrite with core; eauto.

Definition P := False.
Definition P := False.
Definition Q := (False \/ False).
Definition def := P /\ Q.

Axiom solve_P : P = True.
Axiom solve_Q : Q = True.
Hint Rewrite solve_P solve_Q.

(*Beginning of unhelpful hints, none of these help*)
Hint Unfold def.
Hint Transparent def.
Hint Extern 1 def => unfold def.

Axiom def_hint : P -> Q -> def.
Hint Resolve def_hint.
(*End of unhelpful hints*)

Lemma test : def.
Proof.
  crush'. (*fails*)
  unfold def. (*explicit unfold I want to avoid*) crush. (*succeeds*)
  Undo.
  assert P. (*explicit assertions that are even more cumbersome*)
    { auto. (*fails*)
      crush'. (*succeeds *)
    }
  assert Q.
    { auto. (*fails*)
      crush'. (*succeeds *)
    }
  crush'. (*suceeds *)
Qed.
```

I **do not** want to define `def` as a notation since then it will be broken up by `crush` when appearing as a hypothesis.

I realize that this probably has to do something with the order in which `crush` goes about things. My guess is that the `Hint Extern` only comes into play *after* `crush` has called `autorewrite` so it will unfold into goals that at that point will not be solved because it does not call `autorewrite` again. However, I'm not sure since it's hard to determine what `crush` does exactly.

Comment: Can you give us a MWE example containing the definition of `crush`? It is impossible to help you debug how a tactic works if we do not know what it is doing…

Comment: Crush is exported by the `cpdt` library (by Adam Chlipala), however for this example it can be simplified to `Ltac crush' := autorewrite with core; eauto.`. I will update the quesiton

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to register the following if-and-only-if hint to the core autorewriting base:

```
Fact def_hint' : def <-> P /\ Q. reflexivity. Qed.
Hint Rewrite def_hint' : core.
```

This however is not ideal since registering this hint will cause `autorewrite with core` to unfold `def` anytime it occurs as a hypothesis, and not just when trying to solve goals of form `def`. If possible, I would *only* like to unfold `def` in the goal, and not hypothesis (which is why I have it as a definition, and not a notation).

Comment: One possibility would be to have `crush` use another database that is specific to it, where you would add the `Hint Rewrite`, so that it does not pollute `core` and so that using `autorewrite with core` does not unintentionally unfold `def`. In general, I think adding hints to `core` is considered a bad practice. If you want to stick with `core`, I am afraid that you'll have to change `crush` to another tactic which can use other hints than rewriting hints, which are afaik the only one `autorewrite` uses.